# memory cells and c++ pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-management

I am currently wondering something about pointers in c++. A pointer returns me the memory address of variable for instance. So if we say, we want a memory address of a Integer, we normally have a 32-Bit length.

When we say that size of one memory cell is 1 Byte, I would need 4 cells for one Integer (4x8-Bit = 32 Bit). So let's say I have a pointer-address like: `0x613c20` for one Integer (`int a = 10;`).

When this address points to one of the 4 cells in the whole memory, why do I get another value when I increase the cell by just +1? I would stil get the same value, since I am still within one of the 4 cells?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I think I was not so clear in the first posting: 
I didn't mean that I increased the pointer by `pointer++`;

I was inside my debugger and manipulated the memory address of an Integer by just adding a +1, like:

0x1 -> 0x2.

So that means that:

```
int a = 10;
*int b = &a; // 0x1

*0x1 -> 10
*0x2 -> 1203104
```

When the Integer size is 4 byte long, why do I not get 10 as well here?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "increase the cell". If you mean the pointer, you should look up how pointer increments work. Otherwise, you should look up how exactly integers are stored in memory.

Comment: Think those cells in binary forms. Then you will notice that even start is inside those 4 cells, when you take the follow up 4 cells, you will go off-scope and get random values if they are filled and have a random result.

Comment: search "atom interface" from lisp or snobol4 or c.

Comment: This cell concept has a name in C++. It's called **byte**.

Answer (score 1):

When you increment/decrement a pointer, the memory address gets "increased/decreased" by the length of the object type the pointer is declared as (e.g. it would point to the next/previous object of the same type if it would be a sequence of objects of the same type)

A little example:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    int* p_i = &i;

    short c = 'a';
    short* p_c = &c;

    cout << "\npointer to int (4 bytes)\n";

    cout << "adress: " << p_i << "   ";
    cout << "value: " << *p_i << endl;
    ++p_i;
    cout << "adress: " << p_i << "   ";
    cout << "value: " << *p_i << endl;
    ++p_i;
    cout << "adress: " << p_i << "   ";
    cout << "value: " << *p_i << endl;
    ++p_i;
    cout << "adress: " << p_i << "   ";
    cout << "value: " << *p_i << endl;
    ++p_i;

    cout << "\npointer to short (2 bytes)\n";

    cout <<  "adress: " << p_c << "   ";
    cout <<  "value: " << *p_c << endl;
    ++p_c;
    cout <<  "adress: " << p_c << "   ";
    cout <<  "value: " << *p_c << endl;
    ++p_c;
    cout <<  "adress: " << p_c << "   ";
    cout <<  "value: " << *p_c << endl;
    ++p_c;
    cout <<  "adress: " << p_c << "   ";
    cout <<  "value: " << *p_c << endl;
    ++p_c;

    return 0;
}
```

above code outputs:

```
pointer to int (4 bytes)
adress: 0x28ff24   value: 5
adress: 0x28ff28   value: 2686754
adress: 0x28ff2c   value: 2686764
adress: 0x28ff30   value: 2686800

pointer to short (2 bytes)
adress: 0x28ff22   value: 97
adress: 0x28ff24   value: 5
adress: 0x28ff26   value: 0
adress: 0x28ff28   value: -216
```

As you can see, the pointer to short gets "increased" in steps of two as a short occupies 2 bytes of memory as opposed to int, which is longer and takes up four bytes (on my system, that is).

I would suggest referring to documentation regarding lengths of data types (they can vary between systems and compilers) and pointers for further information.

Comment: Ah thank you. The problem is: I didn't increase it by ++, I used the debugger and watchpoints to look to an address of a variable and increased it by just adding +1 so the address went from:  0x28ff24 ->  0x28ff25 and I got another value, by dereferencing them. So why is that so? Normally I would still get the same value since I am still "within" the same variable?

Comment: Glad we shed some more light on the problem.
In your case, I believe it depends on what debugger you are using.
I have a hunch though, - it most likely reads four bytes (the length of the type) from the new position you set it to, thus interpreting the data it finds in that slice of memory as a completely different variable.
E.g. it now reads 0x28ff25 thru 0x28ff28 as opposed to 0x28ff24 thru 0x28ff27 before you changed the address of the first "cell" to point to.

I suggest testing that in your debugger though.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is pointer arithmetic. The result of increasing the pointer (not the value) by one depends on the type of the pointer. In your example the actual address is not incremented by 1, but by 4 (or sizeof(int)). Also, there is no such a thing as

> I would stil get the same value, since I am still within one of the 4 cells